# Show that for any $n\geq 0$, the Fibonacci numbers $f_{2n}$ satisfy $f_{2n}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\binom{n+k}{2k}$

Tags: combinatorics, fibonacci-numbers, combinatorial-proofs

I understand that $f_{2n}$ can be represented by all the possible combinations of squares and dominoes for a $2n$ board.

But I don't understand how to simplify the right hand side in a way that I can intuitively explain that it does the same thing.

Comment: Have you tried using induction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: A tiling of a $1\times2n$ board by squares and dominoes must use an even number of squares. Suppose that it uses $2k$ squares.

- How many dominoes does it use?
- How many tiles does it use altogether?
- How many tilings of the board are there that use exactly $2k$ squares?

By the way, the Fibonacci numbers are usually indexed so that $f_0=0$ and $f_1=1$. In that indexing the number of tilings of a $1\times n$ board with squares and dominoes is $f_{n+1}$, and the sum in your question is $f_{2n+1}$.

Comment: For 2k squares, it would use $2n-2k$ dominoes right? But Ithen the number of total tiles should not be $2n-2k+2k$. I think I'm getting the total number of dominoes incorrect here...

Comment: Okay, I can work backwards that there should be $n-k$ total dominoes (since the total number of tilings is $n+k$ I believe), but I just can't explain intuitively why that is the case.

Comment: @DinkusRex: If you use $2k$ squares, you have $2n-2k$ cells of the board left to fill, but you’re filling them with dominoes, each of which uses $2$ cells, so you need only $n-k$ dominoes. That gives you $(n-k)+2k=n+k$ tiles.